# XCode - iOS localization not taken into account

Tags: ios, xcode, localizable.strings

I have looked around at various answers here but can't figure out what's going on.

My iPhone is in French. I have just one target. I went on the project settings and said "Add Localization" and added French.

I made sure to

- clean/rebuild my app several times
- check that build log shows up the files copy
- remove app from my phone
- run both on phone (8.1) and on the simulator with French
- check that checkboxes are ticked on target/project settings

End result : Storyboard **is localized** but programmable strings **are not**  (the `NSLocalizedString("xxx", nil)` shows xxx instead of yyy)

Any idea ? Here are some screenshots of my configuration

[image: build log]
[image: project files]
[image: fr/localized.strings file settings]

Thanks

Comment: On the simulator or device? There has been some bugs with localization on the simulator since the new XCode.

Comment: this happens on both

Comment: What's the iPhone language set to (Settings->General->Language & Region).?

Comment: french and france. and my storyboard is translated !

Comment: I haven't experienced something like this. You somewhere in the InfoPlist you need to set what .string file to use for localization. I've always used `Localizable.strings` and never had any problem with it.

Comment: Try renaming your .strings file `Localizable.strings`instead of `Localized.strings`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the reason you're having this problem [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014):

> Note: **Localizable.strings** is the default filename iOS uses for
>   localized text. Resist the urge to name the file something else,
>   otherwise you will have to type the name of your .strings file every
>   time you reference a localized string.

If you want to use a different `.strings` file for localization, you need to use the method:

```
- (NSString *)localizedStringForKey:(NSString *)key
                              value:(NSString *)value
                              table:(NSString *)tableName
```

and specify `Localized.strings` as the third (tableName) parameter.

Comment: you are the best ! seriously I don't remember where Localized.strings came from. I think Xcode added it but maybe I had this file before in my project... any way thanks

Comment: No problem. I've never used this feature so it was something new to me as well :)